# Android In-App billing Invalidkeyspecification Crash

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented the IAP billing. But the problem i got is after purchasing the product, the App crashes. Saying the error **Invalidkeyspecification.** But the payment was successfull. When i surf through the web , i came to know there is some problem with the key. here is the code where the error appears that i came through logout trace.

Here i provide the **base64EncodedPublicKey (MIIBI************** and so on)** that i got from the market page

```
   PublicKey key = BillingSecurity.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
        verified = BillingSecurity.verify(key, signedData, signature);
        if (!verified) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signature does not match data.");
            return null;
        }




 try {
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Base64DecoderException.", e);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception g)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception generate Public key.", g);
        return null;
    }
```

NOTE  : I could able to receive the product purchase details and app crash after it.

Please help me here . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Generates a PublicKey instance from a string containing the
 * Base64-encoded public key.
 *
 * @param encodedPublicKey Base64-encoded public key
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if encodedPublicKey is invalid
 */
public static PublicKey generatePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey) {
    try {
        String str = new String(Base64.decode(encodedPublicKey));
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(str);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key specification.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } catch (Base64DecoderException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Base64 decoding failed.");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```